# Erro ao enviar email usando JavaMailSender - Microsoft Exchange 10

Tags: java, spring-boot, javamail

Bom dia!

Não consigo enviar o e-mail. Todas as configurações que tentei utilizar retornam o mesmo erro:

```
WARN  o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: exchange-ipa.dominio.su.net, 25; timeout -1;
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: exchange-ipa.dominio.su.net, 25; timeout -1;
```

Estou utilizando o Spring boot - JavaMailSender, conforme o código abaixo.

Com outro email que temos aqui na empresa, envia sem problemas.

Conseguem me auxiliar?

Agradeço desde já.

Seguem as configs do email:

```
Caixa Postal SMTP: aplicativo.produto@nome.com.br
Domínio\Usuário: Dominio\UJDLKSHFDUH012
Senha: Psjkj1#48K
Host: exchange-ipa.dominio.su.net
Porta: 25 (tentei com a 587 também)
```

Segue o fonte:

```
static final String dsEmail = "Dominio\\UJDLKSHFDUH012";
static final String dsSenha = "Psjkj1#48K";
    
public void enviarEmail(String login, String email, String token, String mensagem, String assunto) throws MailException, MessagingException {

        Global.getSetTokenConfirmaEmail(email.toLowerCase(), token, true, false);
        
        JavaMailSender emailSender = mailSender();
        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        
        helper.setTo(email.toLowerCase());
        helper.setSubject(assunto);
        helper.setFrom("aplicativo.produto@nome.com.br");
        helper.setSentDate(new Date());
        helper.setText(mensagem, true);
        
        try {

            emailSender.send(message);

     } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
     }
    }
    
    public JavaMailSender mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        
        mailSender.setHost("exchange-ipa.dominio.su.net");
        mailSender.setPort(25);
        
        mailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        
        mailSender.setUsername(dsUsuario);
        mailSender.setPassword(dsSenha);

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", true);
        
         mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(props);

        return mailSender;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Está funcionando.

Não sei ao certo se o problema estava nesta configuração :

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true); //alterei para false
```

ou se a equipe que gerencia os servidores mudou algo lá para a liberação, enfim, o código acima funciona.

Obrigado